# In asp.net mvc, is it safe to have an IDisposable model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is the following code sane?

```
public ActionResult MyController()
{
    using(var model=new MyControllerModel())
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    //does framework access model after this point? 
    //If so, I need to rethink

}
```

Comment: I've always thought about this, but I just assumed that everything was disposed of after, since returning the View is essentially the end of the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The framework most definitely accesses the model after it returns an `ActionResult`.  `ActionResults` have their `Execute()` methods called in order to generate the content.

Comment: This is correct.  If you need to dispose of anything within the controller, you can override Controller.Dispose().  You can dispose of your model from within that method.