# ASP.NET MVC - IDisposable models

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created my own logic for something that I think should be a core feature in ASP.NET MVC. I'm posting it here in hope that either someone will show me how to achieve this without custom code or if someone from the MVC team sees it and then realises it's importance and implement this in the future release of MVC.

So, models aren't always the EF object, they can be something else and may contain in them other resources. Especially if you go with ViewModels concept, where they have the model information + anything else that should serve the view.

Anyway, I found myself with models that are IDisposable and I needed a way to dispose them.

After a lot of trials I ended up with the following attribute, which disposes an IDisposable model. It decorates my base Controller class and thus works on any executed action:

```
internal class ModelDisposerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
            var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as IDisposable;
            if (model != null)
                    model.Dispose();

            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Would be happy to hear your thoughts!  :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> The framework most definitely accesses the model after it returns an
>   ActionResult. ActionResults have their Execute() methods called in
>   order to generate the content.
>
> If you need to dispose of anything within the controller, you can
>   override Controller.Dispose(). You can dispose of your model from
>   within that method

[In asp.net mvc, is it safe to have an IDisposable model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143867/in-asp-net-mvc-is-it-safe-to-have-an-idisposable-model)

Comment: Of course, I discovered that the hard way. That's why I'm using OnResultExecuted, which AFAIK is fired after the View is processed (way after the action method completes).